# Small samples and negative binomial estimator

Tags: modeling, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data, small-sample

I have a count dependent variable with one continuous independent variable and one dichotomous independent variable, and I am using a negative binomial regression due to the poisson appearing overdispersed. The confidence interval for alpha excluded zero further confirming the inappropriateness of poisson. I'm concerned however, about the small sample size (20 years, by year) as I've seen recommendations not to use negative binomial for small samples. Can anyone recommend other estimators or ways to correct for this?